# Calculate limit of $e^{-2x}/x$ as $x \rightarrow -\infty$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(\frac{e^{-2x}}{x}\right)$$

The nominator will approach $\infty$ and the denominator will be $-\infty$. I have no idea how to solve this since we end up with a fraction with infinity divided by negative infinity. How do I get started? I should note that I'm not allowed to use lhospital's rule.

Comment: The short version is exponential growth is way bigger than polynomial, so it diverges.  Formally I'd usually show that with L'hospital's (or a power series expansion, which is equivalent).  Are you allowed to use the taylor series expansion of $e^x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There results
$$
\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{e^{-2x}}{x} = -2\lim_{t \to  +\infty} \frac{e^t}{t}.
$$
At this stage you must know that the exponential diverges to infinity faster than any power of $t$. It is not really trivial, and in calculus courses we postpone its proof until we can use De l'Hospital's theorem.

If you know that
$$
e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!},
$$
then $e^x \geq 1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2$ for $x>0$, and therefore 
$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{e^x}{x} = +\infty.
$$